# Swift : retrieving struct values in swiftui view is not working

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to swift and need to define some form of Global Dictionary that I can access the content throughout my project. My understanding is that struct class can be used for that so

I created a struct and appended values to it, now I want to access each of those values in view

this is my product struct

```
struct Product {
    
    let name: String
    let aisleNo:Int
    let location_section: Int
    let location_zone: String
    let productPrice: Int
}
```

then created a global

```
import Foundation

struct Global {
    static var productList = [Product]() 
}
```

this is how I append many products to Product

```
class SearchResult : ObservableObject {
        var productList = [Product]()
         //There could be hundreds of product in the array
        for product in productArray {
            let productName = product.productName!
            let aisleNo = product.productLocation_aisle.value!
            let location_section = product.productLocation_section.value!
            let location_zone = product.productLocation_zone!
            let productPrice =  product.productPrice.value!
            let product_real_id = product._id!
            
            Global.productList.append(Product(name: productName, aisleNo: aisleNo, location_section: location_section, location_zone: location_zone, productPrice: Int(productPrice)))

}
```

this is my search result view where I want to display the content of the Product

```
struct SearchResultView: View {
      var searchResults = Global.productList

        var body: some View {

               VStack {
               List {
                ForEach(model.searchResults, id: \.self) { text in
                    Text(text)
                }
               
               
               }

           }
              }
 }
```

I can seem to get it to show in the searchResultView. What am doing wrong ?
I keep getting this error

> Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Product' conform to 'Hashable'
> Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Product' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Comment: please see and implement latest change in my edit

Comment: @JulianSilvestri thank you. it go ride of the hashable error. but do you know how to fix the second error initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Product' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Comment: Did the string protocol error not go away with the hashable?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri no it did not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set "searchResults" equal to your "productList"
Right now your searchResults is EMPTY. It simply exists as an instance of your struct with no data in it.

one option is to make the variable scope global and then set your new variable = to it

```
self.searchResults = Global.productList
```

--EDIT

You are close.
Where you set your var here

```
var searchResults = Global.productList
```

it needs to be like this.

```
var searchResults = [Product]() // ->Creates an instance of the struct object
```

Then set it equal to your global array.

```
self.searchResults = Global.productList
```

ALSO you should remove you redundant variable `var productList = [Product]()`

Furthermore, some things to note

```
for product in productArray {
      let productName = product.productName!
      let aisleNo = product.productLocation_aisle.value!
      let location_section = product.productLocation_section.value!
      let location_zone = product.productLocation_zone!
      let productPrice =  product.productPrice.value!
      let product_real_id = product._id!
            
      Global.productList.append(Product(name: productName, aisleNo: aisleNo, location_section: location_section, location_zone: location_zone, productPrice: Int(productPrice)))
}
```

you are doing extra work by using all the let variables.
A better way is doing it like so.

```
for product in productArray {

      Global.productList.append(Product(name: product.name, aisleNo: product.aisleNo, location_section: product.location_section, location_zone: product.location_zone, productPrice: Int(product.productPrice)))
}
```

EDIT - Hashable Erorr

try this out

```
struct Product: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let aisleNo:Int
    let location_section: Int
    let location_zone: String
    let productPrice: Int
}
```

Comment: how would that be implemented in View

Comment: @learner101 you need to make your variable GLOBAL so you can keep your structure the same. This is done by making a new swift file , create a struct named "Global" and add -> static var productList = [Product]() . then you need to change your variable name where you append it to -> Global.productList, this allows you to access this variable ANYWHERE, then in VIEW where you need the data, set your new variable  self.searchResults = Global.productLIst

Comment: I'm still having issue displaying the productList in view. Please see my updated question

Comment: ok, the view is showing error about conforming Product to 'Hashable'. I updated the question to show view and the error message